# Join on range in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm rank new to SQL and trying to learn it by solving problems on Hackerank. Here's the problem I'm stuck with. I've two tables

```
Student : id, name, marks

Grades : grade, min_marks, max_marks
```

Essentially the grades table gives,

```
1 0 9
2 10 19
......
```

I'm trying to write the following query, to generate a report containing three columns:  Name, Grade and Mark.  The NAMES of those students who received a grade lower than 8. The report must be in descending order by grade -- i.e. higher grades are entered first. If there is more than one student with the same grade (1-10) assigned to them, order those particular students by their name alphabetically. Finally, if the grade is lower than 8, use "NULL" as their name and list them by their marks in ascending order.

I started composing the query by am lost at the conditional

```
SELECT NAME, GRADE, MARK
FROM MARKS m
INNER JOIN ON GRADE
```

Can someone help me how to go from here.

Comment: you should try and not ask questions related to solving these problems. I can give you the answer, but you will not learn.

Comment: Down voter your argument please?

Comment: Dude, you don't have the names of the tables in the query yet.  SELECT ... FROM mytablename JOIN myothertablename ON ....  Following the ON keyword is where you put the conditions that determine whether a row from one table "matches" a row from the other table.

Answer (score 2):

The above question requires two queries to be executed.
This is how i did it and it works

```
select students.name,grades.grade,students.marks
from students
inner join grades
on students.marks between min_mark and max_mark 
and grades.grade > 7
order by grades.grade desc,students.name;
select 'NULL',grades.grade,students.marks
from students
inner join grades
on students.marks between min_mark and max_mark 
and grades.grade < 8
order by grades.grade desc,students.marks asc;
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

If your question is [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-report/problem),
I have a single query answer:

```
select case when g.grade>=8 then s.name else NULL end,
g.grade, s.marks from students s, grades g
where s.marks between g.min_mark and g.max_mark
order by g.grade desc, s.name asc, s.marks asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is conflicting. Any way.

To get the data of students having less tan grade 8, with name

```
SELECT
    s.name
  , g.grade
  , s.marks
FROM Student s,Grades g 
where  s.marks BETWEEN g.min_marks and g.max_marks
and g.grade < 8
ORDER BY g.grade DESC, s.name ASC
```

If you want the name to be null for student having grade below 8

```
SELECT
    NULL   //or ''
  , g.grade
  , s.marks
FROM Student s,Grades g 
where  s.marks BETWEEN g.min_marks and g.max_marks
and g.grade < 8
ORDER BY g.grade DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you almost there. It isn't totally clear what you are asking because you said you want the name of students who received grade lower than 8. Then you said if grade is lower than 8 use NULL as their name. By these requirements all the students names would be NULL.

```
SELECT
    s.name
  , g.grade
  , s.marks
FROM Student s
JOIN Grades g on s.marks BETWEEN g.min_marks and g.max_marks
WHERE g.grade < 8
ORDER BY g.grade DESC, s.name ASC
```